# Python - Difference between Sonarcube Vs pylint

Tags: python, python-3.x, lint

I'm evaluating test framework, lint and code coverage options for a new Python project I'll be working on.

I've chosen pytest for the testing needs. After reading a bunch of resources, I'm confused when to use Sonarcube, Sonarlint , pylint and coverage.py.

Is SonarLint and Pylint comparable? When would I use Sonarcube?

I need to be able to use this in a Jenkins build. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 6):

Sonarlint and pylint are comparable, in a way.

Sonarlint is a code linter and pylint is too. I haven't used sonarlint, but it seems that analyzes the code a bit deeper that pylint does. From my experience, pylint only follows a set of rules (that you can modify, by the way), while sonarlint goes a bit further analyzing the inner workings of your code. They are both static analyze tools, however.

Sonarcube, on the other hand, does a bit more. Sonarcube is a CI/CD tool that runs static linters, but also shows you *code smells*, and does a security analysis. All of what I'm saying is based purely on their website.

If you would like to run CI/CD workflows or scripts, you would use Sonarcube, but for local coding, sonarlint is enough. Pylint is the traditional way, though.

Comment: Both Sonarlint and Pylint are free lint tools.
SonarQube is a commercial software.

Answer (score 1):

Nicholas has a great summary of Pylint vs Sonarlint.
(Personally I use the Sonarlint)

Although the question is older, I thought I'd answer the other part of your question in case anyone else has the same question; internet being eternal and all.

Coverage.py as it sounds, runs code coverage for your package. SonarQube then uses the report that coverage.py makes and does things with it and formats it in a way that the Sonar team decided was necessary. Coverage.py is needed if you want to use SonarQube for code coverage. However, if you just want the code smells from SonarQube, it is not needed.

You were also asking about when to use SonarQube, coverage.py, and Jenkins.

In Jenkins, you would create a pipeline with several stages. Something along the following lines:

1. Check out code (automatically done as the first step by Jenkins
2. Build code as it is intended to be used by user/developer
3. Run Unit Tests
4. run coverage.py
5. run SonarQube

Comment: I've added a couple of reviews from developers about SonarQube from https://www.gartner.com/reviews/market/application-security-testing/vendor/sonarsource/product/sonarqube and posted them in separate comments for readability

Comment: This was implemented at our organization from a decree from management to allow them to check a box to say our codebases are analyzed for quality and security... everyone scrambled to get it done, and in the end, our code is now graded based one some arbitrary rules. Bogus issues ...
June 16, 2022 https://www.gartner.com/reviews/market/application-security-testing/vendor/sonarsource/product/sonarqube

Comment: June 17, 2022
Great way to create busywork/homework for your bored developers to work on...
Overall, as a developer with multiple years of experience, I was not very impressed with SonarQube.. the "issues" it identifies it are rarely truly issues and overall I felt the push to implement this in our organization was short-sighted and only created unneeded "homework" for our developers https://www.gartner.com/reviews/market/application-security-testing/vendor/sonarsource/product/sonarqube

Comment: Here's a good example of the SonarQube response to a developer trying to incorporate MyPy type checking capabilities into SonarQube: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/pythons-mypy-support-in-sonarqube/12790 SonarQube apparently aggregates a large number of tools in order to be able to sell support for over 20 languages and apparently does not have any type checking capabilities to rival Mypy.

Comment: I've added some dev reviews of SonarQube from https://www.gartner.com/reviews/market/application-security-testing/vendor/sonarsource/product/sonarqube and posted them separately for readability. I've formed the impression that SonarQube is positioned to capture dollars from corporate where execs who don't connect with their dev teams, which are however now becoming important as corporations identify themselves as "digital businesses", and so now need to have some protection from being blamed for code quality concerns. "It's not our fault, we implemented SonarQube". Corrections are welcome.

Comment: Nicholas firstly says he's never used Sonarlint, but simply quotes the summary headline from the website, but usefully points out Sonarlint doesn't have it's own coverage report but just repackages the one from coverage.py. No-one with any experience of Sonarlint or SonarQube has posted here yet, and although you use Sonarlint you say, you don't mention anything about it's abilities. The only information we have on SonarQube is what I've commented from dev reviews. It woiuld be great to get some content in the answers here but nothing yet.